# Dúvida sobre funções

Tags: python

Boa noite, desculpe se algo relacionado foi postado em algum momento. Tentei procurar mas nao tive sucesso. Estou tentando fazer uma função e no resultado, seja impresso os dados das variaveis, mas informa que ela nao está definida.

```
def calcula(salario,percentual):
    valor_do_aumento = (salario/100)*percentual
    salario_novo = (salario + (salario/100)*percentual)

salario = float(input('Digite o salario: '))
percentual = float(input('Qual aumento: '))

print(salario_novo)
```

Comment: Deu uma olhada nos links acima e conseguiu achar a solução?

Comment: Elias, muito obrigado, consegue entender, removi os parametros de dentro dos parenteses e utilizei o return salario_novo, com isso consegue imprimir o retorno!

Comment: Boa mano! Sucesso no teu aprendizado